# How to read the text in a input tag in a p tag?

Tags: javascript, html, speech-synthesis

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<p class="section-description" id="txt">Today I went to the zoo. I saw a(n) <input placeholder="noun"> <input placeholder="adjective"> jumping up and down in its tree. He <input placeholder="verb, past tense"> <input placeholder="adverb"> through the large tunnel that led to its <input placeholder="adjective"> <input placeholder="noun">. I got some peanuts and passed them through the cage to a gigantic gray <input placeholder="noun"> towering above my head. Feeding that animal made me. </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
let synth = window.speechSynthesis;

let inputTxt = document.getElementById('txt');

function speak() {
if (synth.speaking) {
    console.error('speechSynthesis.speaking');
    return;
}
    let utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(inputTxt.innerHTML);

    let selectedOption = voiceSelect.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-name');
    for (i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {
        if (voices[i].name === selectedOption) {
            utterThis.voice = voices[i];
        }
    }
    synth.speak(utterThis);
}
```

When I input some text into the input box the code still reads "placeholder...", How do I make the code to speak the inputted text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grabbing the `innerHTML` which isn't going to read `text`, it's going to read `html`.

In order to concatenate your `input` elements and your `text`, you're actually going to need to combine the two somewhere in your code. Probably within the `speak` function.

The simplest way to do this is probably the following:

```
let compiledStr = "";
inputTxt.childNodes.forEach(i =>
compiledStr += (i.nodeType === 3) ? 
  i.textContent : 
  i.value);
```

What the above does is iteratate over the child nodes of the `inputTxt` element. It grabs the `textContent` (plain text) of any `text nodes` or the `value` of any `element nodes` and stitches them together in order.

**A Simple Example To See How This Works** *be sure to click the "compile" button below the input sentence*

```js
let synth = window.speechSynthesis;
let inputTxt = document.getElementById('txt');

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let compiledStr = "";
  inputTxt.childNodes.forEach(i => compiledStr += (i.nodeType === 3) ? i.textContent : i.value);

  console.log(compiledStr);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="section-description" id="txt">Today I went to the zoo. I saw a(n) <input placeholder="noun" id="noun1"> <input placeholder="adjective" id="adjective1"> jumping up and down in its tree. He <input placeholder="verb, past tense" id="verb1"> <input placeholder="adverb" id="adverb1">    through the large tunnel that led to its <input placeholder="adjective" id="adjective2"> <input placeholder="noun" id="noun2">. I got some peanuts and passed them through the cage to a gigantic gray <input placeholder="noun" id="noun3"> towering above my head. Feeding that animal made me. </p>
</div>
<hr>
<button>Click Me to Compile</button>
```

**The following should work for you using your current code:**

```js
let synth = window.speechSynthesis;
let inputTxt = document.getElementById('txt');


function speak() {
let inputTxt = document.getElementById('txt');

let compiledStr = "";
inputTxt.childNodes.forEach(i => compiledStr += (i.nodeType === 3) ? i.textContent : i.value);

if (synth.speaking) {
    console.error('speechSynthesis.speaking');
    return;
}
    let utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(compiledStr);

    let selectedOption = voiceSelect.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-name');
    for (i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {
        if (voices[i].name === selectedOption) {
            utterThis.voice = voices[i];
        }
    }
    synth.speak(utterThis);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p class="section-description" id="txt">Today I went to the zoo. I saw a(n) <input placeholder="noun" id="noun1"> <input placeholder="adjective" id="adjective1"> jumping up and down in its tree. He <input placeholder="verb, past tense" id="verb1"> <input placeholder="adverb" id="adverb1"> through the large tunnel that led to its <input placeholder="adjective" id="adjective2"> <input placeholder="noun" id="noun2">. I got some peanuts and passed them through the cage to a gigantic gray <input placeholder="noun" id="noun3"> towering above my head. Feeding that animal made me. </p>
</div>
```